Setting GstNvEncoderPreset property for nvcodec (nvautogpuh264enc) Element with Gstreamer
When trying to set GstNvEncoderPreset property for gstreamer Element in Rust, I got error
The following code doesn't compile
Minimal example:
use gst::ElementFactory;

fn main() {
    gst::init().expect("Init gst");
    ElementFactory::make("nvautogpuh264enc")
        .name("nvcodec")
        .property("preset", "p1")
        .build()
        .expect("Built element");
}

Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
gst = { version = "0.23.2", package = "gstreamer" }

Error says
thread 'main' panicked at src/stream_src.rs:132:10:
property 'preset' of type 'GstNvAutoGpuH264Enc' can't be set from the given type (expected: 'GstNvEncoderPreset', got: 'gchararray')

That's obviously that it wants GstNvEncoderPreset type, but I couldn't find any information where I can import that type or somehow create it manually. Also tried use integer, error was the same
How can I set preset for nvautogpuh264enc in Rust?

Please provide us with a reproducible example, mentioning the cargo.toml file and its dependency section. Your example must include the content of main.rs with all use statements to make reproducing the error as easy as possible.

@Raeisi thx for remark, it's done
